# PHP search a string for a email address

Tags: php, regex

Hi Im attempting to search a string to see whether it contains a email address - and then return it.

A typical email vaildator expression is:

```
eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email);
```

However how would I search if that is in a string, for example return the email address in the string:

"Hi my name is Joe, I can be contacted at joe@mysite.com. I am also on Twitter."

I am a bit stumped, I know I can search if it exists at all with \b around it but how do I return what is found.

Thanks.

Comment: That expression is incorrect, by the way.

Comment: First hit on "email address regular expression": http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [In PHP, how do I extract multiple e-mail addresses from a block of text and put them into an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901070/in-php-how-do-i-extract-multiple-e-mail-addresses-from-a-block-of-text-and-put)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add $regs as the last argument:

```
eregi("...", $email, $regs);
```

Comment: Note that `eregi` is deprected for a long time now. Jonathan Sampson's answer is better!

Answer (score 9):

You could use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), which would output it to an array for use.

```
$content = "Hi my name is Joe, I can be contacted at joe@mysite.com. I am also on Twitter.";
preg_match("/[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})/i", $content, $matches);

print $matches[0]; // joe@mysite.com
```

Comment: Be aware that in this case, you will need to remove the ^ and $ from the beginning and end of your pattern - ^ means to match the start of the string, and $ matches the end of the string, so it won't find a "match" unless the email is the whole string.  To search for a contained email address, you would change:

"^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$" to "[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})"

Comment: I decided to carry on using eregi, thanks for the pointer Renesis.

Comment: Joobool, remember to accept the answer that you found helpful.

Comment: I changed pattern to
`"/[_a-z0-9-]+(?:\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(?:\.[a-z]{2,3})/i"`
in order to get only email matches.

Without `?:` at the beginning of groups regexp is returning also the group matches arrays.

Comment: @bumbu that rocked ..!! Thanks for the perfect regex.

Answer (score 0):

A better PCRE for extracting an ADDR_SPEC is:

```
 /[a-z0-9\._%+!$&*=^|~#%'`?{}/\-]+@([a-z0-9\-]+\.){1,}([a-z]{2,6})/
```

But if you really want to extract an RFC 2822 then you need something like:

```
 /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/
```

C.