# In PHP, how do I extract multiple e-mail addresses from a block of text and put them into an array?

Tags: php, regex, email

I have a block of text from which I want to extract the valid e-mail addresses and put them into an array.  So far I have...

```
   $string = file_get_contents("example.txt"); // Load text file contents
   $matches = array(); //create array
   $pattern = '/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.([A-Za-z0-9_-][A-Za-z0-9_]+)/'; //regex for pattern of e-mail address
   preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches); //find matching pattern
```

However, I am getting an array with only one address.  Therefore, I am guessing I need to cycle through this process somehow. How do I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code is almost perfect, you just need to replace `preg_match(...)` with `preg_match_all(...)`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I am getting close now.  My output however looks a little strange to me.  I seem to be getting arrays within my array as follows:  Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => example@slu.edu ) [1] => Array ( [0] => edu ) )

Comment: I am looking for simply one array with each key containing an e-mail address.

Comment: @HumbleHelper preg_replace_all will create new array elements for submatches of anything that was in parentheses in the original pattern. You had parentheses around the last part is the domain in your pattern. To fix this you can just append $matches = $matches[0] at the end. Also, look at Clay Hinson's answer. He deserves the accepted answer.

Answer (score 29):

You're pretty close, but the regex wouldn't catch all email formats, and you don't need to specify A-Za-z, you can just use the "i" flag to mark the entire expression as case insensitive. There are email format cases that are missed (especially subdomains), but this catches the ones I tested.

```
$string = file_get_contents("example.txt"); // Load text file contents

// don't need to preassign $matches, it's created dynamically

// this regex handles more email address formats like a+b@google.com.sg, and the i makes it case insensitive
$pattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i';

// preg_match_all returns an associative array
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

// the data you want is in $matches[0], dump it with var_export() to see it
var_export($matches[0]);
```

output:

```
array (
  0 => 'test1+2@gmail.com',
  1 => 'test-2@yahoo.co.jp',
  2 => 'test@test.com',
  3 => 'test@test.co.uk',
  4 => 'test@google.com.sg',
)
```

Comment: +1 for more detail than my answer, example code, and a pattern that catches subdomains. This should be accepted answer.

Comment: This solution is buggy unless you fix it. The above regex breaks 'email@domain.info' type emails where last part consists of 4+ characters. You regex returns 'email@domain.inf'. Please fix.

Comment: Also it breaks first.lastname@domain.be. Returns only 'lastname@domain.be'.

Comment: It works, but it can not grab email like: HIDDENFORLOGICALREASONS@cameranh.rs.gov.br, returning only HIDDENFORLOGICALREASONS@cameranh.rs.go. To workaround this, we need to increase the number of optional args (? on regex represents it) to: "/[a-z0-9_.\-\+]{1,256}+@[a-z0-9\-\.]{1,256}+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2,3})?(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i". Remembering that it does not work with subdomain emails. So I recommend @Eric-Karl response.

Comment: Buggy indeed - doesn't catch required formats for me.

Comment: This one misses firstname.lastname@example.com type email addresses. They become "lastname@example.com"

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution.

Answer (score 19):

I know this is not the question you asked but I noticed that your regex is not accepting any address like '`myemail@office21.company.com`' or any address with a subdomain. You could replace it with something like :

```
/[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}/
```

which will reject less valid e-mail (although it is not perfect).

I also suggest you read [this article on e-mail validation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html), it is pretty good and informative.

Comment: Thank you for your sugestion! I have used @Clay Hinson response but that did not work with subdomains. I merged the 2 answers and i get it: "/[a-z0-9_.\-\+]{1,256}+@[a-z0-9\-\.]+\.([a-z]{2,4})/i" I have used strtolower() on email var, so it does not require A-Z

Comment: This regex works, the one from @Clay Hinson answer doesn't

Answer (score 5):

This detects all mail addresses:

```
$sourceeee= 'Here are examplr mymail@yahoo.com and my-e.mail@goog.com or something more';

preg_match_all('/[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}/i', $sourceeee, $found_mails);
```

then you can use `$found_mails[0]` array.

Answer (score 2):

This regex will extract all unique email address from a url or file and output each in new line. It will consider all subdomains and prefix suffix issues. Find comfortable to use it.

```
<?
$url="http://example.com/";
$text=file_get_contents($url);
$res = preg_match_all(
"/[a-z0-9]+[_a-z0-9\.-]*[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})/i",
$text,
$matches
);
if ($res) {
foreach(array_unique($matches[0]) as $email) {
echo $email . "<br />";
}
}
else {
echo "No emails found.";
}
?>
```

check here for more reference : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Spot on. This seems to cover ever type of email

Answer (score 0):

It worked better for me:

```
<?php
$content = "Hi my name is Joe, I can be contacted at joe@mysite.com.";
preg_match("/[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})/i", $content, $matches);
print $matches[0];
?>
```

Some of the others didn't accept domains like: name@example.com.sv

I found it on: http://snipplr.com/view/63938/

Answer (score 0):

This function works fine without using regex. So it is really faster and low resource hungry.

```
<?php
function extract_email_addresses($str){
    $emails = array();
    $str = strip_tags( $str );
    $str = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str); 
    $str = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/", "", $str); 
    $remove_chars = array (',', "<", ">", ";", "'", ". ");
    $str = str_replace( $remove_chars, ' ', $str );
    $parts = explode(' ', $str);
    if(count($parts) > 0){
        foreach($parts as $part){
            $part = trim($part);
            if( $part != '' ) {
                if( filter_var($part, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false){
                    $emails[] = $part;
                }                
            }
        }
    }
    if(count($emails) > 0){
        return $emails;
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}

$string = "Guys, please help me to extract valid sam-ple.1990@gmail.co.uk email addresses from some text content using php
example , i have below text content in mysql database ' Life is more beautiful, and i like to explore lot please email me to sample@gmail.com. Learn new things every day. 'from the above text content i want to extract email address 'sample-x@gmail.com' using php regular expressions or other method.";

$matches = extract_email_addresses( $string );
print_r($matches);

?>
```