# How to add multiple email ids into a single text field in HTML and PHP?

Tags: php, html

I simply want to add multiple emails in single textfield using PHP and HTML. I want user to be able to enter multiple email ids into a HTML textfield. It should happen like Hotmail.

Comment: You probably want parse all emails from a string. The same problem is solved in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/q/3901070/2492795

Comment: How to use it ? i'm not getting

Answer (score 1):

HTML  multiple Attribute helps you take multiple argument

Use php's explode function to separate emails

```
<?php

echo<<<_END

<html>
<body>
<form action="php.php" method='POST'>
Enter emails seperated by comma: <input type="text" name="mail" multiple>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
_END;

if(isset($_POST['mail']))
{
$t = $_POST['mail'];
$arra=explode(",",$t);  
for($i=0;$i<count($arra);++$i)
   {echo $arra[$i];
    echo"<br>";
   }
}
?>
```

The above code gives the following output
[image]

---

In order to take emails seperated by whitespace just change the explode function to

```
$arra=explode(" ",$t); // comma replaced with whitespace
```

This should work fine.

Comment: Thankyou golden_flash.. but i want to write emails like hotmail or facebook message....means if we write email in textfield it should be highlighted and there should not be need of adding commas in textfield., it should be separated automatically....how can i do that ?

Comment: Sites like hotmail and facebook use whitespace for separation, I have added how to do it in my answer.

Comment: but how to highlight those emails?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/AuYUcCQ.png        kindly check this link .. i want the output like the attached image...i want to email like that...please hav a look  .

Comment: Change input type to 'text' from 'mail' and $arra=explode(" ",$t) works.  For something like that you need to know Ajax and Javascript.                                                        Are you familiar with Ajax ?

Comment: Well your question was to simply add multiple emails in single textfield using php and html which I think is resolved.                                                      Also it would be off-topic for me to tell you how to use Ajax when you are not familiar with it.                                                                                                       Try learning Ajax and if you have problems you can head back to StackOverflow :-)

Comment: well.. my problem is still not resolved... becoz i want to separate emails and they should be highlighted...i am still trying.