# Validate email inside textarea

Tags: javascript, php, validation, email

I made a form with only a textarea, so i want the form be validate only if the message has a valid email inside the textarea, 
But if i use `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`, it's allows only email, without space or message.

How can i fix it?

My code:

```html
  <form action="contact.php" method="post">
        <p>
        <textarea rows="1" style="height:1em;" id="text" autofocus>Hello my name is M2PV,&#13;&#10;</textarea>
     </p>
        <p>
        <input value="send" type="submit" id="send">
     </p>
   </form>
```

```js
$('form').submit(function(){
 message = $(this).find('#text').val();
 
 $.post('contact.php',{
 message:message
}, function(data){
 if(data.error=='ok'){
  alert('formulaire ok');
 }else{
  alert('email invalid');
 }
},"json");
 return false;
});
 });
```

```html
<?php
 $e= array();
 $e['error'] = "Entrez votre email";
 if(!filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
  $e['email_invalid'] = "email_invalid";
 }else{
  $e['error'] = 'ok';
  $message = $_POST['message'];
 
 $to = 'xxxx@xx.com';
 $sujet = ' Contact site ';
 $msg = $message;
 //mail($to, $sujet, $msg);
 
 }
 
 echo json_encode($e)
?>
```

Comment: how about parse all addresses and validate them?

Comment: Stop, separate out the email field from the message field, you know, similar to how everyone else does it

Comment: To play devils advocate... what happens if the message contains three email addresses?

Comment: @J.Schilling That will allow multiple space, but will allow only emails

Comment: @tib you also want to allow message in the textarea? or its only for multiple email validation ?

Comment: Yes i want allow messages

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to parse all e-mail addresses and validate them

[**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901070/in-php-how-do-i-extract-multiple-e-mail-addresses-from-a-block-of-text-and-put) you can find inspiration for parsing multiple e-mail addresses and put them in an array. After that you could iterate over the array and validate them