# How to make a PHP regular expression assertion apply to the whole pattern when finding email addresses?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find email addresses in text posted by users to my online forum, and change them into Bulletin Board Code (BBCode). So for instance:

```
example@yahoo.com
```

would become:

```
[mail]exmaple@yahoo.com[/mail]
```

However I don't want to change email addresses that are already in BBCode.  So for instance, I don't want:

```
[mail]exmaple@yahoo.com[/mail]
```

to become:

```
[mail][mail]exmaple@yahoo.com[/mail][/mail]
```

Therefore I need to add a negative lookbehind assertion to my regular expression to ensure that an email address is not preceeded by the characters [mail] (or just ]).

The PHP code I'm using is:

```
$pattern = '#(?<!])([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*@\S+\.\w+)#';
$bbcode = '[mail]$1[/mail]';
preg_replace($pattern, $bbcode, $text);
```

The problem I have is that the negative lookbehind is only applied to the first character for the email address seeking sub-pattern.  For example when applied to the text:

```
[mail]example@yahoo.com[/mail]
```

The result is:

```
[mail]e[mail]xample@yahoo.com[/mail][/mail]
```

So the negative lookbehind finds [mail]e, but the rest of the email address xample@yahoo.com still validates. I reaise that this is because of the way the email address seeking sub-pattern is written, because it allows for any number of characters before the @.

How can I change the regular expression to make the negative lookbehind appliy to the whole of the email address seeking sub-pattern, whilst still successfully catching the majority of email addresses being posted?

Comment: Note that `]example@yahoo.com[` is not inside `[mail]` / `[/mail]` tags, but `(?<!])\b([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+@\S+\.\w+)(?!\[)` [will not match it](https://regex101.com/r/ROtVOX/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a word boundary at the beginning of regex to avoid matching the text partially, and also use `+` instead of `*` for the username part in email regex. Try using this regex,

```
(?<!])\b([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+@\S+\.\w+)(?!\[)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0YnLKc/1)**

Answer (score 0):

You may match and skip the substrings between `[mail]` and `[/mail]` and only match the email pattern you have in all other contexts:

```
'~\[mail].*?\[/mail](*SKIP)(*F)|[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*@\S+\.\w+~si'
```

To skip matching email in any tags like the ones you have:

```
'~\[(\w+)(?:\s+[^]]*)?].*?\[/\1](*SKIP)(*F)|[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*@\S+\.\w+~si'
```

See the PHP demo:

```
$rx = '~\[mail].*?\[/mail](*SKIP)(*F)|[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*@\S+\.\w+~si';
// Or, for any tag:
// $rx = '~\[(\w+)(?:\s+[^]]*)?].*?\[/\1](*SKIP)(*F)|[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*@\S+\.\w+~si';
$text = preg_replace($rx, '[url=mailto:$0]$0[/url]', $text);
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/K3TJU3/2) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/ROtVOX/2).

**Details**

- `\[mail].*?\[/mail](*SKIP)(*F)` - `[mail]`, then any 0+ chars as few as possible, and then `[/mail]`, `(*SKIP)(*F)` discards the match and start the next search from the end of the failed match
- `|` - or
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*@\S+\.\w+` - an email-like pattern.

`$0` in the replacement pattern refers to the whole match value, no need to wrap the whole pattern with capturing parentheses.

NOTE: If your email extraction regex fails to work as expected, check [In PHP, how do I extract multiple e-mail addresses from a block of text and put them into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901070/in-php-how-do-i-extract-multiple-e-mail-addresses-from-a-block-of-text-and-put).

Comment: @dearsina Your test might not be valid as you only tested the "general" regex. I provided **two** in case the tag meant was `[url]` and not `[mail]`. The *approach* is correct when one wants to skip matches in certain tag, and match everywhere else.

Comment: That's fair, you can always substitute tags, but what happens when there is not tag?

Comment: @dearsina When there is no tag [it is added](https://regex101.com/r/K3TJU3/2). As expected.

Comment: How odd, in PHP it doesn't seem to add anything: https://3v4l.org/790HB

Comment: @dearsina  [**In PHP**](https://3v4l.org/baTcL), my solution works well. Does not replace inside `[mail]....[/mail]`, adds everywhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I realise the PHP code example I posted didn't fit in with my question, so I've edited it to $bbcode = '[mail]$1[/mail]';