# Use regex to strip out emails

Tags: regex

I know that this is a notoriously difficult topic.  The best regex that I've found after trawling many different answers is the one at http://emailregex.com/

It works great at validating an email address, but I'm struggling to alter this regex to find *all* email addresses in a string.

I'm using the PHP version of the regex.

How would I go about using this regex to find all of the email addresses in a string?

I know about the `preg` functions, my PHP code isn't as much the problem as adapting that regex.

```
$redacted = preg_replace_callback(
            "/$emailRegex/i",
            function ($matches) {
                return '[' . $this->getHashedValue($matches[0]) . ']';
            },
            $input
        );
```

Comment: What kind of string?  Are e-mail addresses separated by something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In PHP, how do I extract multiple e-mail addresses from a block of text and put them into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901070/in-php-how-do-i-extract-multiple-e-mail-addresses-from-a-block-of-text-and-put)

Comment: Maybe using PHP's `preg_match_all` is what you need.

Comment: Just remove the start `^` and end `$` string anchors.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus that's brilliant, thanks, that's finding the first instance of an email address... how would I go about finding all of them?

Comment: Use `preg_replace` because it automatically applies the `/g` modifier for you.

Comment: Thanks @MonkeyZeus ... I'll abandon the callback.  It works properly with just preg_replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a working regular expression, you can use PHP's [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace all (non-overlapping) matches by a certain string, in our case `""` (to remove them).

```
preg_replace($your_regex, "", $your_string)
```

This should strip all matches from your string.

Also, as @MonkeyZeus commented, if your regex contains the start anchor (`^`) or the end anchor (`$`), make sure to remove those before using `preg_replace`. Otherwise, the only match you can get will be the entire string, if it matches.

Comment: Thanks, this just returns the email addresses but is closer to what I'm looking for.  I was hoping to strip them out.  If I get an array of them I suppose I could iterate the array and slice them out, but that feels bad.