# How to identify mail addresses of specific domain using Regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to wrap some html elements for gmail address in a given string. How can i do it with php regex.

Input

```
$string = 'Sample text name@gmail.com another text name2@gmail.com,name2@yahoo.com';
```

Output I want

```
$string = "Sample text <div class='gmail'>name@gmail.com</div> another text <div class='gmail'>name2@gmail.com</div>,name2@yahoo.com";
```

Comment: It's not clear that you even tried to solve this on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like (wraps all email adresses):

```
$string = 'Sample text name@gmail.com another text name2@gmail.com,name2@yahoo.com';
echo preg_replace("/([\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-])+/i", "<div class='gmail'>$1</div>", $string);
```

Gmail only:

```
$string = 'Sample text name@gmail.com another text name2@gmail.com,name2@yahoo.com';
echo preg_replace("/([\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@gmail.com)+/i", "<div class='gmail'>$1</div>", $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take practically any [email search regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050789/php-search-a-string-for-a-email-address) and just replace the domain part with a fixed string. Then searching and replacing isn't much effort:

```
 = preg_replace('/\b\w[\w+.%!-]+@gmail.com\b/', "<div class=gmail>$0</div>", $src);
                      # ^^^ allowed special chars still insufficient
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('(\w+?@\w+?\.\w+)', '<div class="gmail">$0</div>', 'Sample text name@gmail.com another text name2@gmail.com,name2@yahoo.com');
```